# Georeference automaticlly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

In ArcGIS the function called "Auto Registration" and it can automatically georeference raster

[image]

Is there a way in QGIS to do the same?
I seek in the transformation settings and in the setting georeferencer but found nothing.

Answer (score 5):

I think the closest available tool is the GRASS tool [i.points.auto](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/i.points.auto.html) which aims to automatically generate ground control points to geocode rasters.

It is available for GRASS 7.0 so it *may* also be available in QGIS 2.14. Otherwise you may need to use GRASS GIS 7 which already comes bundled with QGIS 2.14.

Comment: Missing tool `i.points.auto`: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/465591/missing-tool-i-points-auto-in-the-qgis-grass-provider