# automatically georeference QgsGeometry.fromPoint features on creation

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, georeferencing, vector-layer

Is there a way to automatically georeference fromPoint features upon creation?

I use this layer URI:

```
      self.pinLayer =  QgsVectorLayer(
          "Point?crs=epsg:3857&field=id:integer&field=description:string(120)&field=x:double&field=y:double&field=pluscode:string(20)&index=yes",
          "Pins",
          "memory")
```

I then set the pins using the QgsGeometry.fromPoint method:

```
        feature = QgsFeature()
        feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point))
```

Which works fine as you can see:

[image]

But the points are not georeferenced. 
Is there a way to add / do that right during creation?

I've found this [old entry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189016/georeference-automaticlly-in-qgis) but its for raster layers and it also requires some user interaction (setting ground control points)
I want to do it programmatically

Comment: Hello cmon_sig,  Are you setting point = QgsPoint(x, y, z)  or point = QgsPointXY(x,y) where x and y are from your feature['x'] and feature['y'] fields?

Comment: Hi @CaryH not sure I understand your question, but if you are referring to a z dimension coordinate: I'm not using or setting a z coordinate

Comment: OK cmon_sig.   How are you setting the geometry for <point> in your program?  You are using it here -  feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point)).   Somewhere in your program you need to either get the geometry from an existing Qgspoint or you need to set it with -    point = QgsPointXY(1024477.6376,5996078.71604)

Comment: hi Cary H I'm setting it like this: 

######

`self.pinTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(self.canvas)`

######

`QObject.connect(self.pinTool, SIGNAL("canvasClicked(const QgsPoint &, Qt::MouseButton)"), self.place_pin)`

######

`def place_pin(self, point, button):
(desc,ok) = QInputDialog.getText(
         #  (desc) = QInputDialog.getText(
                self.iface.mainWindow(),
                "Description",
                "Description for pin at %.2f, %.2f" % 
                (float(str(point.x())),float(str(point.y()))),`