# Missing tool `i.points.auto` in the QGIS GRASS provider

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin

I have the latest version of QGIS `3.32.2-Lima` installed.

I have installed GRASS `7.8` and `8.3`, which is confirmed in OSGeo4W.

[image: OSGeo4W]

GRASS plug-in is enabled in QGIS.

[image: Plugins]

But I cannot find the [i.points.auto](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/addons/i.points.auto.html) tool in the `Processing toolbox` list.

[image: Processing roolbox]

Moreover I cannot find this tool in GRASS 8.3 itself!

[image: GRASS 8.3]

What's wrong with this tool? Has it been renamed?

Comment: It's an add-on, you need to [install it](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/g.extension.html).  I don't use osgeo4w so don't know, but might be worth checking the advanced installer to see if it provides grass add-ons...?

Comment: @user2856  Thanks. Do you have `i.points.auto` in QGIS or GRASS (maybe separately installed)? Can you take a screenshot of which extension it is in? I looked in the GRASS settings and found `g.extension` there, but GRASS crashes with a critical error. I probably need to read how to install GRASS extensions inside QGIS.

Comment: Probably not relevant as I use Linux not Windows/OSGeo4W, but I used `g.extension` in GRASS.  It wasn't simple, I had to separately install a heap of development packages so the add-on would compile from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i.points.auto:` is a plugin and it's not part of the GRASS core. It must be installed separately.

More info here:
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/addons/

Thanks to [user2856](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2856/user2856) for the clarification.

When installing this extension in OS `Windows 10`, I encountered the following problems:

1. When launching `g.extention` I got the error `Cannot find the executable git`.

The first problem was solved by adding this line to the `grass83.bat` file:

`path C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%PATH%`.

2. The `[Errno 13] Permission denied:` error occurred when installing the extension.

It can be resolved by running `grass83.bat` as administrator.

Currently the tool works from GRASS, but it is not visible in the processing toolbox in QGIS.

New modules installed through the GRASS 8.3 interface are located in the folder:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\GRASS8\addons\bin`,

while GRASS is installed in a different folder:

`C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\grass`

This probably explains the lack of extension in QGIS.

Most importantly, GRASS addons are not yet implemented in QGIS. Issue:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/53048